# Redirect internal outgoing traffic to an external machine with iptables

Tags: iptables

is this possible with iptables?:

- I've a machine with no internet access but in a lan where exists other machines with internet access
- So i want all http traffic FROM my machine to go throw a machine on the lan (ip: 10.10.5.165) and the response go back to my machine

e.g: if i ask for google.com from my machine, then i need that traffic go to 10.10.5.165 namely do like 10.10.5.165 ask for google.com and finally the answer go back to my machine

i know that i can make ssh act as a SOCK server and do the same thing that i'm trying to accomplish but i want to kwow if is possible only with iptables.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called [source NAT](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-6.html#ss6.1).

Comment: ok so i can use something like:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 10.10.5.165
but that doesn't work :(

Comment: You're using this on the other machine?

Comment: no, i'm using it in my machine (the one that doesn't have internet access), the machine with ip 10.10.5.165 is a windows machine

Comment: Well you can't do anything on *your* machine; you don't have Internet access.

Comment: thats the point, from my machine i can ping and access the machine 10.10.5.165 and that machine has internet access, so i want to forward my request to 10.10.5.165

Comment: Routing is all you need to forward your packets. But if the other machine doesn't know what to do with the packets then there's no point in forwarding them.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments in @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer I believe installing a `http proxy server` would be a better solution.

For example, if your machine is `10.10.5.165` and it has lan access to `10.10.5.166`(the computer with internet)

1. Install a `proxy server` (such as [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)) on `10.10.5.166`
2. Configure the `proxy settings` of the browsers on `10.10.5.165` to point to `10.10.5.166`

And you should be able to open web sites. Unfortunately, you won't be able to use this `proxy server` for `http` connections. If you want to have full internet access, then you'll need to configure `iptables`.